# how to get the link from google hangout button?

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

How do you get the link of a google hangout button from my website, that was generated by goole's api. Im trying to store the link and store  in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hangout url using getHangoutUrl() in your hangout app

```
https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout#gapi.hangout.getHangoutUrl
```

Comment: can u send the link to your database from google hangout api?

Comment: Yes you can send links to your database